# Correcting boot problem:   mount of NTFS drives went wrong

Tags: mount, ntfs, recovery-mode

After my upgrade to 12.04, whenever Ubuntu tried to boot up it prompted an error indicating that it can't mount (NTFS) drives and I had to press **S** twice, once for each drive, to get to the login screen.

Now that I have disabled the auto mounting of drives, I guess I've made a mistake and Ubuntu no longer starts. I tried recovery modes (although I don't exactly know how to handle them), and then I see only a line which says mounting failed and permission was denied.  It doesn't move past this.

How can I get Ubuntu to boot again?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. What exactly did you do? Have you edited a config file? Perhaps `/etc/fstab`? If so, you'll need to boot from the Live CD/USB, and add that file's content to the question.

Comment: I don't know much about commands in ubuntu. I just used a disk manager software that I had downloaded from software center (I always used to search "storage" to find it, don't recall its name exactly) and it had an option to mount disks in read-only on start up which I disabled (for both of my NTFS partions) and from then on after I choose to enter UBUNTU there's just a blank page.

Comment: Is it a Wubi install?